# SQL using MAX(column) command

Tags: sql

Can you help me answer these queries using max and min commands.

I've just started SQL and I am attempting to:

- Find the lowest price of any CD
- Find the number of CDs costing 11.99
- Find the title of the most expensive rock CD

I'm using the min and max commands in my query but i cannot seem to get the correct queries. Below is a link to the tables that I'm referring to.

The code I have so far is:

```
1)SELECT cdPrice FROM `CD` order BY MIN(cdPrice)
2)
3)SELECT cdTitle FROM `CD` where cdGenre = 'Rock' AND order BY MAX(cdPrice)
```

Tables that I'm referring to:

[image]

Comment: You should really do your homework yourself.

Comment: you haven't mention what DBMS you are using, and it's easy to find out how to use Max and Min in a correct way, and the question 2. you can use key word 'count()' to do it.

Comment: Google is a wonderful friend! Give it a try: https://www.google.com.au/#q=how+to+use+max+and+min+in+sql

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework, and really basic homework at that.  Stackoverflow isn't really a place to ask how to select something from a table, any tutorial on SQL you find on the internet should be read before asking for wisdom from SO.  I don't think it will be helpful to any other users.

Answer (score 0):

## #1

The lowest price of any CD is just a basic minimum select.

```
SELECT MIN(Price)
FROM CD
```

## #2

We need to use a basic `COUNT` and where clause to get the count for that specific price.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM CD 
WHERE Price = '11.99'
```

## #3

With #3 we need to find the highest price. We can do this in multiple ways, the way that I would do it is with a subquery and where clause just off my head.

```
SELECT Title, Price 
FROM CD 
WHERE Price = 
(
    SELECT MAX(Price) FROM CD
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. select min(cdPrice) from CD;
2. select cdID from CD where Price=11.99;
3. select a.cdTitle, a.Price, a.cdId
   from CD a 
   inner join (select cdId, MAX(Price) as max_p
      from CD
      group by Genre
      having Genre = 'Rock'
   ) b a.cdId = b.cdId and a.Price = b.max_p;
```

It gets a bit complicated to get the title of the most expensive Rock CD. Here are my answers. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MIN(column_name) FROM table_name
```

Try do homework by your self, its fast way to understand SQL.